# Ajustar div para exibir o centro da imagem em telas menores sem mexer no tamanho da imagem

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tenho uma imagem assim:
[image]

Em telas menores, quero que ela seja vista ao centro, sem alterar tamanho e escala da imagem
[image]

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Boa noite, você pode utilizar object-fit do css Leia:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/nupqf4hz/

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o que você está querendo é que a altura seja constante, enquanto a largura não.

Acho que isto pode ser resolvido com:

```
  background: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
```

```css
div {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/24/08/53/flower-1219360_960_720.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
 
 
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 90vh;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

No exemplo acima é possível redimensionar a imagem na borda dela, conforme for estreitando a imagem, será mostrado apenas o centro.